# Magento : Get product configurable options on category page

Tags: php, javascript, magento

In the category listing page on my Magento site, I've a column on that right that loads the product's view page thru AJAX when a user clicks on a product. I'm able to retrieve all content from the view page like images, tabs etc, but I'm not able to retrieve the product's configurable options because they're stored as a javascript variable.

Any ideas on how I can retrieve that info as well?

Edit - Better explanation: I'm trying to let the user configure the product right from the category page, by showing them all the options without having to navigate to each product's view page. So far, I've only been able to get the html but the dropdowns are empty. And thats because all the options & their prices are stored as a javascript variable in the view page. So my question is, how do i get those options thru an ajax call & load the dropdowns & have them work exactly the way they do in the product view page?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve values or keys (name/type/etc) for configurable options?

Comment: Trying to retrieve everything, including the interface where the user selects the options and the price gets updated automatically. I'm able to get the html for that, but the list of options is empty!

Comment: errr... What concretely are you trying to retrieve from product/category? Just did not get the meaning of word 'everything' and relate it to the question...

Comment: I'm trying to let the user configure the product right from the category page, by showing them all the options without having to navigate to each product's view page. So far, I've only been able to get the html but the dropdowns are empty. And thats because all the options & their prices are stored as a javascript variable in the view page. So my question is, how do i get those options thru an ajax call & load the dropdowns & have them work exactly the way they do in the product view page?

Comment: Ha! I got it! Are you trying to do the right floating sidebar of this page for some reasons?

Comment: If by 'this page' you mean the product view page, then yes!

Comment: oh i am sorry... I forgot to add a link and gone away... http://www.icentre.nl/macbook-pro-13-intel-core-i7-2-8ghz here is "this page" =)

Comment: that's not what i want to do. i just want to get the product configuration interface from the product view page to the category page and have it work in the exact same way. so far, i've only gotten empty dropdowns!

Comment: Could you give some screenshots of what dropdowns you got or links or anythig? Because Magento has lot of dropdowns ;)

Comment: Here you go - http://kartikrao.in/category-page.png .  As you can see i've got the item size dropdown to the category page, but that dropdown is empty!

Comment: Could not see any image. Are you sure the link is correct? http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/341/desktop1024.jpg/

Comment: try www.kartikrao.in/category-page.png with the www prefix

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses JS, it is true. It uses `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable` class to render configurable products. And you shoulda be interested in its `getJsonConfig()` method. It is used within the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` template to render the javascript code which does the magick, as you said.

So, in the template it looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
```

In the browser it looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var denyProduct = {"62":["12","9"]}        
    var spConfig = new Product.Config({"attributes":{"70":{"id":"70","code":"manufacturer","label":"Manufacturer","options":[{"id":"11","label":"Fischer","price":"10","oldPrice":"10","products":["61","66"]},{"id":"12","label":"Queen mum","price":"20","oldPrice":"20","products":["62"]}]},"122":{"id":"122","code":"size","label":"Maat","options":[{"id":"9","label":"M","price":"15","oldPrice":"15","products":["61","62"]},{"id":"10","label":"S","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["66"]}]}},"template":"\u20ac\u00a0#{price}","basePrice":"150","oldPrice":"150","productId":"64","chooseText":"Kies een optie...","taxConfig":{"includeTax":true,"showIncludeTax":true,"showBothPrices":false,"defaultTax":19,"currentTax":19,"inclTaxTitle":"Incl. BTW"}});
</script>
```

And the code which creates all that javascript options is (`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable::getJsonConfig()` method):

```
$attributes = array();
$options    = array();
$store      = $this->getCurrentStore();
$taxHelper  = Mage::helper('tax');
$currentProduct = $this->getProduct();

$preconfiguredFlag = $currentProduct->hasPreconfiguredValues();
if ($preconfiguredFlag) {
    $preconfiguredValues = $currentProduct->getPreconfiguredValues();
    $defaultValues       = array();
}

foreach ($this->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
    $productId  = $product->getId();

    foreach ($this->getAllowAttributes() as $attribute) {
        $productAttribute   = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
        $productAttributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
        $attributeValue     = $product->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());
        if (!isset($options[$productAttributeId])) {
            $options[$productAttributeId] = array();
        }

        if (!isset($options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue])) {
            $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue] = array();
        }
        $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue][] = $productId;
    }
}

$this->_resPrices = array(
    $this->_preparePrice($currentProduct->getFinalPrice())
);

foreach ($this->getAllowAttributes() as $attribute) {
    $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
    $attributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
    $info = array(
       'id'        => $productAttribute->getId(),
       'code'      => $productAttribute->getAttributeCode(),
       'label'     => $attribute->getLabel(),
       'options'   => array()
    );

    $optionPrices = array();
    $prices = $attribute->getPrices();
    if (is_array($prices)) {
        foreach ($prices as $value) {
            if(!$this->_validateAttributeValue($attributeId, $value, $options)) {
                continue;
            }
            $currentProduct->setConfigurablePrice(
                $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent'])
            );
            Mage::dispatchEvent(
                'catalog_product_type_configurable_price',
                array('product' => $currentProduct)
            );
            $configurablePrice = $currentProduct->getConfigurablePrice();

            if (isset($options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']])) {
                $productsIndex = $options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']];
            } else {
                $productsIndex = array();
            }

            $info['options'][] = array(
                'id'        => $value['value_index'],
                'label'     => $value['label'],
                'price'     => $configurablePrice,
                'oldPrice'  => $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                'products'  => $productsIndex,
            );
            $optionPrices[] = $configurablePrice;
            //$this->_registerAdditionalJsPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Prepare formated values for options choose
     */
    foreach ($optionPrices as $optionPrice) {
        foreach ($optionPrices as $additional) {
            $this->_preparePrice(abs($additional-$optionPrice));
        }
    }
    if($this->_validateAttributeInfo($info)) {
       $attributes[$attributeId] = $info;
    }

    // Add attribute default value (if set)
    if ($preconfiguredFlag) {
        $configValue = $preconfiguredValues->getData('super_attribute/' . $attributeId);
        if ($configValue) {
            $defaultValues[$attributeId] = $configValue;
        }
    }
}

$taxCalculation = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation');
if (!$taxCalculation->getCustomer() && Mage::registry('current_customer')) {
    $taxCalculation->setCustomer(Mage::registry('current_customer'));
}
```

And the code which connects those values to the `<select>` elements is located within the `Product.js` file.

If you just want to get all attributes, used within some category, here's the solution: assume you have a variable `$_productCollection` filled with category products. Then you can perform this performance-breaking code:

```
$setIds = array();

foreach ($_productCollection as $k => $product)
{
    $setIds[] = $product->getAttributeSetId();
}

/** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Collection */
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
$collection
    ->setItemObjectClass('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')
    ->setAttributeSetFilter($setIds)
    ->addStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->setOrder('position', 'ASC');

$collection->load();
```

So you shall get all the attributes (with repeats) within the `$collection` variable.

Hope, this will help you somehow.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I now have a clear understanding of where the options come from. But i'm afraid I will not be able to use this solution because, as you mentioned, it is performance-breaking! I'll have to look at other ways of achieving this. Thanks again though! Appreciate it.

Comment: If you cache the `$_productCollection` variable or even the while attribute collection - the performance will raise ;) When we do the magick in the office - we do not care 'bout performance in Magento - it is mostly useless =)

Answer (score 0):

This can take up considerable server resources as there can be many options for each product. Best way is to use ajax to only load ALL the options when asked for. I found this extension that will load colors first, then when you mouse over it will give you all the product options.

http://www.consofas.com/plugins/options-quickview-for-configurable-products-in-magento/